# text-align is not working when I insert a link

Tags: html, css

I have my code, which is in http://jsfiddle.net/truxx/v8jnyn9h/

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
body,
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url("code2.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div#negro {
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}
div#nav {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 40px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px
}
div.contenedor_general:hover {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
div.contenedor_general {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top .2s;
}
div.contenedor_uno {
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #101010;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #707070;
}
div.contenedor_dos {
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #707070;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #101010;
}
p.texto_uno,
p.texto_dos {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
a.links1,
a.links2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div#general {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  /*background-color:red; */
}
div#ucleed {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  /* background-color:black; */
}
.text_line {
  clear: both;
}
div#ofertas {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 5px solid #202020;
  background-image: url(ucleed2.png);
}
div#twitter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-image: url(ucleedtwitter.png);
  visibility: hidden;
}
div#ofertas:hover div#twitter {
  visibility: visible;
}
div#novedades {
  margin: auto;
  /* width:640px; */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
div#body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 580px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.ucleed {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="novedades"></div>
<div id="nav">
  <div id="negro"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="contenedor_general">
        <div class="contenedor_uno">
          <a href="inicio.html" class="links1">Inicio</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_dos">
          <a href="inicio.html" class="links2">Inicio</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="contenedor_general">
        <div class="contenedor_uno">
          <a href="ucleed.html" class="links1">Live</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_dos">
          <a href="ucleed.html" class="links2">Live</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="contenedor_general">
        <div class="contenedor_uno">
          <p href="/bio.html" class="texto_uno">Biografía</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_dos">
          <p href="/bio.html" class="texto_dos">Biografía</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="contenedor_general">
        <div class="contenedor_uno">
          <p href="/proyectos.html" class="texto_uno">Proyectos</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_dos">
          <p href="/proyectos.html" class="texto_dos">Proyectos</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="contenedor_general">
        <div class="contenedor_uno">
          <p href="/contacto.html" class="texto_uno">Contacto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor_dos">
          <p href="/contacto.html" class="texto_dos">Contacto</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="general">
    <div id="ucleed" class="text_line">
    </div>
    <div id="ofertas" class="text_line">
      <div id="twitter">
        <!--           <img src="ucleedtwitter.png" class="ucleed">  -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vulputate est quis erat maximus, ac blandit lorem pulvinar. Nunc eros mauris, vulputate pharetra ex vel, imperdiet fermentum nunc. Sed facilisis tincidunt posuere. Aenean cursus, nunc
        vel sollicitudin facilisis, erat mauris consequat nulla, non tristique augue eros cursus velit. Proin cursus tortor lectus, at pretium urna mattis at. Quisque cursus mi sit amet dolor mollis porta. Suspendisse gravida eleifend lectus, quis tincidunt
        leo volutpat vel. Aenean sed nulla id nibh interdum efficitur. In vehicula placerat orci sit amet condimentum. Quisque cursus risus a elit aliquet posuere. Nulla facilisi. Donec bibendum bibendum nulla, non vulputate ipsum dapibus at. Nam iaculis
        finibus elit, eget mattis ligula sodales vel. Etiam vitae venenatis arcu. Vivamus vel semper quam. Vivamus semper id elit ac efficitur. Cras vehicula lectus nibh, pellentesque auctor felis tincidunt non. In nec massa ac augue fermentum condimentum.
        Vivamus bibendum, felis a tristique aliquam, tortor massa consequat arcu, ac convallis est justo quis lacus. Curabitur euismod egestas volutpat. Cras mi est, suscipit sit amet tellus eget, sollicitudin luctus lectus. Ut nec suscipit lorem. Maecenas
        posuere dolor ut neque interdum posuere. Phasellus nec volutpat urna. Praesent pellentesque sed nisi eget sagittis. Donec tortor erat, suscipit eget nisl iaculis, gravida maximus libero. Donec ut massa ultricies, sodales mauris at, vehicula eros.
        Praesent eu ullamcorper mi.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to insert the links in the first two boxes of the `nav` bar, and `text-align: center` stops working.

The html code (just the link part) is:

```html
<div class="contenedor_uno">
  <a href="inicio.html" class="links1">Inicio</a>
</div>
<div class="contenedor_dos">
  <a href="inicio.html" class="links2">Inicio</a>
</div>
```

An the CSS part is

```css
a.links1,
a.links2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I don't have a clue about how to correct this. If I change the `a` tag for a `p` tag, the text does align, but the link stops working, of course.

Comment: You need to format your code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use text-align in the div:

```
.contenedor_uno,.contenedor_dos{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a tag is a inline tag so text-align doesn't work on it whereas p tag is block tag  that's why text-align works. So you should try to give the text-align property to the parent div or you can make the a tag block by css and use `text-align : center;`.

**CSS:**

```
.contenedor_uno,.contenedor_dos{
    text-align: center;
}
```

**OR**

```
a.links1,a.links2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzx6hzkf/)

Answer (score 0):

**simple solution-**
add this to your code(to the css of the link):

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

It will be like:

```
a.links1,
a.links2 
{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Working example :

http://jsfiddle.net/v8jnyn9h/2/

```css
*{

  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  font-family: helvetica;


}

body,
html {
 min-height: 100%;
}

body{
 background-image:url("code2.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 }


div#negro {
 margin: auto;
 height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
}

div#nav {


 margin: auto;
 width:1000px; 
 height:40px;
 background-color:red;

}



ul{

list-style: none;
width: 1000px; 
height: 40px;

}

li{

float:left;
width: 100%;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
background-color:green;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:0px

}



div.contenedor_general:hover{

margin-top:-40px;

}

div.contenedor_general{

width:200px;
height:80px;
background-color:yellow;
-webkit-transition:margin-top .2s;

}


div.contenedor_uno{


width:200px;
height:36px;
background-color:#101010;
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom: 4px solid  #707070;

}


div.contenedor_dos{

width:200px;
height:36px;
background-color: #707070;
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom: 4px solid #101010;

}

p.texto_uno, p.texto_dos{

text-align:center;
margin-top:10px;
color:white;

}

a.links1, a.links2{
width: 100%;
display: block;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:10px; 
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
}












div#general {

 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 0px; 

 width:1000px;
 height: 800px;
 /*background-color:red; */

}

div#ucleed {
 float:right;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 300px;
 height:240px;
/* background-color:black; */
}

.text_line {
    clear: both;
    }

div#ofertas {

 float: right;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width:300px;
 height:480px;
 border: 5px solid #202020;
 background-image:url(ucleed2.png);

}

div#twitter{
 
 width: 300px;
 height: 480px;
 border: 5px solid black;
 background-image:url(ucleedtwitter.png);
 visibility: hidden;
}

div#ofertas:hover div#twitter{
 visibility:visible;
}

div#novedades {
  margin: auto;
 /* width:640px; */
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;

}



div#body {
 
 margin-top:20px;
 width:640px;
 height:580px;
 background-color:purple;

}


.ucleed{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

  <head> 

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>efecto Hover en menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css" />

         
   </head>

<body>

  <div id="novedades">
          </div>


 <!-- Aquí empieza la descripción del navegador. --> 
   
  

   <div id="nav">
   
<div id="negro"> </div>

      <ul> 
    

           <li>   <div class="contenedor_general"> 



               <div class="contenedor_uno">
          
                         <a href="inicio.html" class="links1">Inicio</a>
               </div>
              
               <div class="contenedor_dos">
           
                         <a href="inicio.html" class="links2">Inicio</a>

              </div>

  </div></li>  




       <li> 
               <div class="contenedor_general"> 



               <div class="contenedor_uno">
          
                         <a href="ucleed.html" class="links1">Live</a>
               </div>
              
               <div class="contenedor_dos">
           
                         <a href="ucleed.html" class="links2">Live</a>

              </div>

  </div>

       </li>       





      <li>

               <div class="contenedor_general"> 



               <div class="contenedor_uno">
          
                         <p href="/bio.html" class="texto_uno">Biografía</p>
               </div>
              
               <div class="contenedor_dos">
           
                         <p href="/bio.html" class="texto_dos">Biografía</p>

              </div>

  </div>

     </li>      





 
      <li>


               <div class="contenedor_general"> 



               <div class="contenedor_uno">
          
                         <p href="/proyectos.html" class="texto_uno">Proyectos</p>
               </div>
              
               <div class="contenedor_dos">
           
                         <p href="/proyectos.html" class="texto_dos">Proyectos</p>

              </div>

  </div>

     </li>      






     <li>


              <div class="contenedor_general"> 



               <div class="contenedor_uno">
          
                         <p href="/contacto.html" class="texto_uno">Contacto</p>
               </div>
              
               <div class="contenedor_dos">
           
                         <p href="/contacto.html" class="texto_dos">Contacto</p>

              </div>

  </div>


     </li>



     </ul>

<!-- Aquí  finaliza la descripción del navegador. --> 

  

<!-- Aquí  la descripción de las tablas. --> 


  
   <div id="general">

     
          <div id="ucleed" class="text_line">

          </div>  
      
          <div id="ofertas" class="text_line">  


                 <div id="twitter">
                 <!--           <img src="ucleedtwitter.png" class="ucleed">  --> 

                  </div>
      
          </div>
     
          
          

          <div id="body">

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vulputate est quis erat maximus, ac blandit lorem pulvinar. Nunc eros mauris, vulputate pharetra ex vel, imperdiet fermentum nunc. Sed facilisis tincidunt posuere. Aenean cursus, nunc vel sollicitudin facilisis, erat mauris consequat nulla, non tristique augue eros cursus velit. Proin cursus tortor lectus, at pretium urna mattis at. Quisque cursus mi sit amet dolor mollis porta. Suspendisse gravida eleifend lectus, quis tincidunt leo volutpat vel. Aenean sed nulla id nibh interdum efficitur. In vehicula placerat orci sit amet condimentum. Quisque cursus risus a elit aliquet posuere. Nulla facilisi. Donec bibendum bibendum nulla, non vulputate ipsum dapibus at. Nam iaculis finibus elit, eget mattis ligula sodales vel.

Etiam vitae venenatis arcu. Vivamus vel semper quam. Vivamus semper id elit ac efficitur. Cras vehicula lectus nibh, pellentesque auctor felis tincidunt non. In nec massa ac augue fermentum condimentum. Vivamus bibendum, felis a tristique aliquam, tortor massa consequat arcu, ac convallis est justo quis lacus. Curabitur euismod egestas volutpat. Cras mi est, suscipit sit amet tellus eget, sollicitudin luctus lectus. Ut nec suscipit lorem. Maecenas posuere dolor ut neque interdum posuere. Phasellus nec volutpat urna. Praesent pellentesque sed nisi eget sagittis. Donec tortor erat, suscipit eget nisl iaculis, gravida maximus libero. Donec ut massa ultricies, sodales mauris at, vehicula eros. Praesent eu ullamcorper mi.

</p>

          </div>


   </div>


   
   </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```